# setting up VOCE api in ubuntu

Tags: bash, scripts, java, openjdk

I am using ubuntu 14.04 . I recently downloaded a speech recognition and synthesis api called voce. For installation it told me to run the build.sh file. When I run this script it pops out some errors like

```
> ./build.sh: line 1: /bin/javac: No such file or directory ./build.sh:
> line 5: /bin/jar: No such file or directory
```

**Additional info:**
I ran java --version commadn and got version 1.7.0_75 as output.

this is the build.sh script file:

```
${JDK_HOME}/bin/javac -classpath ../../../lib/freetts.jar:../../../lib/jsapi.jar:../../../lib/sphinx4.jar Utils.java SpeechSynthesizer.java SpeechRecognizer.java SpeechInterface.java
cd ..
${JDK_HOME}/bin/jar cmvf voce/MANIFEST.MF ../../lib/voce.jar voce/*.class
cd ../../lib
${JDK_HOME}/bin/jar uvf voce.jar gram/*.gram
${JDK_HOME}/bin/jar i voce.jar
cd ../src/java/voce
```

I even set up the JAVA_HOME variable in etc's enivironment file to different paths based on javac location in my folder. I'm desperate for help.. please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You have installed a JRE (Java Runtime Environment) and you need a JDK (Java Development Kit). `/bin/javac` and `/bin/jar` are included in the JDK package.

Therefore in your case:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

Comment: I  did like you mentioned .. I get the same error.  i navigated into /usr/lib/jvm  and i can see the following folders  default-java , java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64,  java-7-openjdk-amd64,java-8-oracle.. all have javac in their bin folder. Also when I echo the JAVA_HOME variable I get /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
I don't seem to understand  what the problem is.